# how to get the values from php to javascript variable is it possible

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

this is my php script from which am returning the value to the ajax calling it

```
<?php

$questionid=$_GET['qid'];
$answer=$_GET['clickedvalue'];
$dbconnect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','quiz')or die("Error Connecting to database");
$query="select answer from question_answer where id=$questionid";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbconnect,$query);
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $dbanswer=$rows['answer'];  
    }


    //array values which will be passed to json 
    $result=array('correct'=>'Correct Answer',
                   'incorrect'=>'Incorrect Answer'
                );

    if($dbanswer==$answer)
        {
            //json to be passed to next page with key value pair
            echo json_encode(array('display_msg'=>$result['correct'],'points'=>'positive'));    
        }
    else{
            echo json_encode(array('display_msg'=>$result['incorrect'],'points'=>'negative'));
        }   

?>
```

and this is my ajax code

```
   $.ajax({
        url:'checkanswer.php',
        dataType:'json',
        data:{'clickedvalue':clickedvalue,'qid':qid},
        success:function(data){
        $this.find(".report").html(data.display_msg);
        $this.delay(1000).slideUp();
        }

        });
```

So my question is how do i store the value of data.points object that is passed from the php as a json  in the javascript variable or is it not possible to store in javascript variable directly if yes how and if no what will be the way to get the value and store somewhere

Comment: store it where ? what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: problem solved just trying to fetch the json object did some mistake so before

Answer (score 2):

Just add a temp variable before calling ajax
Some thing like this

```
var myTempVariable; //Temp JS variable to use somewhere else
$.ajax(
{
    url: 'checkanswer.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 
    {
        'clickedvalue': clickedvalue,
        'qid': qid
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $this.find(".report").html(data.display_msg);
        $this.delay(1000).slideUp();
        myTempVariable = data; //assugn value to temp varaible
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

in your ajax success function :

```
var myVariable = data.points;
```

This might help